# Get by column names in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Currently I am getting the values from statement like this:

```
[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement,0)] retain];
```

I want to get the values by entering the column name like this:

```
[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ReturnStatement,@"FirstColumn")] retain];
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what is your motivation for using a string instead of a numeric index.

Comment: suggest you read the documentation before posting a question. http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html

Comment: I read the documentation. That is why i am asking have anyone done this thing by a customize code. I want to use column name because if i change the db columns or selection in query i will not have to worry about the index. Hope you understand now why people want selection by column name.

Comment: @falconcreek - using a string instead of a numeric index lends flexibility, considering that the order of the columns might change.  Also greatly improves debugging and readability, which I find valuable. It isn't very helpful to recommend Naveed should read the documentation, which is really vague and incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html. You will have to iterate over the column indices returned by the query to add the column names to an array or dictionary that you can reference later to lookup the column index given a name to provide to the column_text function which only accepts the column index as an integer parameter.

One of the problems of using sqlite directly instead of CoreData which will handle this for you.