# How to access columns by their names and not by their positions?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, tuples

I have just tried my first sqlite select-statement and got a result (an iterator over tuples). So, in other words, every row is represented by a tuple and I can access value in the cells of the row like this: `r[7]` or `r[3]` (get value from the column 7 or column 3). But I would like to access columns not by their positions but by their names. Let us say, I would like to know the value in the column `user_name`. What is the way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821744/get-by-column-names-in-sqlite-statement-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on my question [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/124403/sqlite3-how-to-see-column-names-for-table):

```
cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(tablename)")
print cursor.fetchall()
```